# How to use SSIS to compare single value in File1 header to total row count in File2 (csv)

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, ssis-2012, flat-file

I'm tasked with creating a step that validates reported value from an external organization with the actuals delivered from same organization.

This organization will drop 2 files on our server.
File1 contains a single numerical value

File2 contains a .csv with multiple rows.

I don't need to load the data anyplace I just want to check that the value in file1 matches the total row count in file2.

Any recommendation on how to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to compare values between two files, **there is not need to use SSIS**. You can use a simple C# script to read files using `System.IO.StreamReader` and store the values within two variables then compare them. Or just import both files into SQL and use an SQL query to compare values.